# Nginx - server change - redirect all traffic to new ip address?

Tags: nginx

I want to change the server of a website and usually the way of doing it, is this:

1. Check the TTL of the domain which points to the current IP address.
2. Change the A-Record of the the current domain to point to the new IP address.

But in this case there are still requests, that will point to the current IP address until all nameservers understood the change.

How can I prevent that? Is the NGINX reverse proxy the right tool to direct all traffic to the new IP address? And if so, do I just need to do it this way on the current server and thats it?

```
location ~ \ {
    proxy_pass http://newipaddress:8000;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reverse proxy is the perfect tool for this kind of change for a number of reasons. Here are a few:

- As you mentioned some name servers will provide the old ip address to the clients, so some clients will request the old server
- with DNS change you would need a new public ip address or at least change your nat configuration on your corporate firewall
- in the case there are failures on the new server switching back takes more time due to ttl

So to sum it up: Changing the backend ip on the nginx minimizes changes on the corporate firewall and gives you the possibility to switch very quickly.

Configuration as you mentioned is just:

```
location ~ \ {
   proxy_pass http://newipaddress:8000;
}
```

Site note: Alternatively you could write the ip addresses of your backend server and a fitting hostname in your /etc/hosts file and mention this hostname in your proxy_pass directive. This has the advantage that in case of switching servers you just would need to change the entry in /etc/hosts instead of changing multiple configuration files.